# create dynamic grid layout

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

My goal is to create nxn tic tac toe game in React. Now I have the `board` class wrapping squares.
This is the css:

```
.board {
  display: grid;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  **grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);**
     
}
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

In the .board css how can I make this dynamic and not 3 - for example if the grid is 4X4 then I will have to do repeat(4,1fr) etc...how it will be generic for all sizes?

Comment: you have to pass value to repeat, how will it know what `n x n` box it has to make ? depending on `width` and `height` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you specifically want a React solution, I've put together a demo for you  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-khorana-5t2xi?file=/src/App.js).

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [gridSize, setGridSize] = useState(4);
  const boardRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    boardRef.current.style.setProperty("--grid-size", gridSize);
  }, [gridSize]);

  const createSquares = () => {
    let html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
      html.push(<div key={i} className="square"></div>);
    }
    return html;
  };

  function handleClick() {
    setGridSize(gridSize === 4 ? 3 : 4);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className="my-button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle grid
      </button>

      <div ref={boardRef} className="board">
        {createSquares()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.board {
  --grid-size: 4;
  /* Start with 4x4 */
  display: grid;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  grid-template: repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr) / repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr);
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.my-button {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

---

I would use a `CSS` [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), which you can set via `JavaScript` at any time.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.my-button');

const board = document.querySelector(".board");

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  board.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    board.innerHTML +='<div class="square"></div>';
  }
  board.style.setProperty("--grid-size", 3);
}
```

```css
.board {
  --grid-size: 4; /* Start with 4x4 */
  display: grid;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  grid-template: repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr) / repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr);
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.my-button {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>  
</div>

<button class="my-button">
  Change to 3x3
</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/dhtcuen4/14/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can that be achieved without jquery? Pure css/react

Comment: @Kaki6876 I'm using native JavaScript—no jQuery.